# Is there a way to implement DataGridView SaveItem button without using TableAdapters?

Tags: c#, datagridview, save

I'm currently trying to implement DataGridView SaveItem operation...

Since I already have CRUD methods written and I didn't use TableAdapters I'm wondering if there is a smart way of implementing Save without using adapter.

My current take was implementing on CellEditEnd ike this:

```
private void djelatnikDataGrid_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            DataGridViewRow gridrow = djelatnikDataGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex];
            DataRowView rowview = (DataRowView)gridrow.DataBoundItem;
            DataRow row = rowview.Row;
            if (row.RowState != DataRowState.Unchanged || djelatnikDataGrid.IsCurrentRowDirty)
            {
                if (djelatnikDataGrid.Rows.Count == (e.RowIndex+1))
                {
                    djelatnik_ListaNovihRedaka.Add(row);
                }

                djelatnik_ListaRedakaSaPromjenama.Add(row);
            }
        }
```

I want to check if the record is a new row or existing one that was edited, then I add it to NewRowList or UpdatedRowList based on RowIndex and on SaveItemClick I go foreach row and call Insert/Update methods like this:

```
private void btnSaveDjelatnik_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (DataDirty)
            {
                foreach (DataRow row in djelatnik_ListaNovihRedaka)
                {
                    Djelatnik djelatnik = new Djelatnik();
                    djelatnik.ImePrezime = row["ImePrezime"].ToString();
                    djelatnik.Zvanje = row["Zvanje"].ToString();
                    djelatnik.RadnoMijesto = row["RadnoMjesto"].ToString();
                    r.InsertDjelatnik(djelatnik);
                }

            if (vozilo_ListaRedakaSaPromjenama.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (DataRow row in djelatnik_ListaRedakaSaPromjenama)
                {
                    Djelatnik djelatnik = new Djelatnik();
                    djelatnik.ImePrezime = row["ImePrezime"].ToString();
                    djelatnik.Zvanje = row["Zvanje"].ToString();
                    djelatnik.RadnoMijesto = row["RadnoMjesto"].ToString();
                    r.UpdateDjelatnik(djelatnik);
                }
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Promijene su spremljene u bazu podataka!");
        }
    }
```

I know it's kind of ambiguous question but If somebody could point me to a direction I'd appreciate it

Comment: There's another way. You can delete all related records in database and then reinsert all data  in you grid to DB. so you don't need to know which is new/existing. It will help you less calculation and steps...

Comment: Yes but it would take a lot of time? Is this a real solution or workaround

Comment: In accounting flow, we always did like that. Calculating how many quantity added or reduced takes more time and risky. Delete by ID and then reinsert latest data in grid. Cheer!

Comment: I'm going to try this... thanks for your time

Comment: if it's ok, up vote my comment :D

Comment: If it's OK, post an answer and I will mark it as correct

Comment: Not trying to offend anyone, but deleting records instead of updating them is a terrible way to implement what you want to archieve in my opinion. If your application crashes you will lose your data which you probably don't want to risk if you are working for a company since it could cost you loads of money or even the job.

Comment: Deleting,inserting need transaction. No one works without transaction. No risk. No load. No more implementation. We work reusable code. @Luke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to implement Add/Edit form for inserting or editing new records.

Edit form opens on double clicking the record and add form has AddItem button

This will save me a lot of time and trouble...

Thanks for suggestions anyway ~ ChenChi

Comment: Probably the best solution. Most DGV based apps use extra forms/fields for editing.

Comment: Thank you for feedback Luke

Answer (score 0):

There's another way. You can delete all related records in database and then reinsert all data in you grid to DB. so you don't need to know which is new/existing. It will help you less calculation and steps...

Don't forget use `Transaction` for deleting and reinserting.

Comment: Using `Transaction` will probably remove the risk of losing data. It will be a problem if the database uses an `Autoincrement Integer` as `PrimaryKey`. If this PK links the row to anything else in the database it will cause problems later on due the fact this row will get a new PK.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Dictionary(Of DataGridView, Boolean)` `oDic_RowToWasEdited` for your Rows.
As soon as you update your `DataGridviews DataSource` put `each Row into the Dictionary` with the `Value False`. Whenever a `Cell gets edited` `change` the rows dictionary entry `to true`.

As soon as you want to `save to the Database` check first if your `dictionary contains the row`. `If not` it means you have a `new Row`. `If` the dictionary `contains that key check its value`. If it's `true` you know that you have to `update it`.

Althrough I'm sure there a better ways of doing so using the datatables RowState attribute, I think this should get you going.

Comment: I'm thinking of disabbling SaveItem button and just adding a form for inserting/editing rows

Comment: That's probably the best way to go without a Tabeladapter.